# Register inputs (click) - write the inputs

Tags: javascript

This app register where you click on the screen, then it writes the inputs on the page. The text is responsive, you can change the dimension or orientation of the webpage and it still will be in the middle with the right size to fill the entire page. With a double click the program will restart.

http://jsfiddle.net/Diquadro/ah1nfxkb/

```js
class Text {
  constructor (element) {
    this.element = element
  }

  write (inputs) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length - 1; ++i) {
      this.element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${i + 1}: ${inputs[i]}`))
      this.element.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
    }
    this.element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${inputs.length}: ${inputs[inputs.length - 1]}`))
  }

  erase () {
    while (this.element.firstChild) {
      this.element.removeChild(this.element.firstChild)
    }
  }

  resize () {
    this.element.style.fontSize = '50vw'
    // fitting the text the whole page
    for (let i = 50; window.innerWidth < this.element.offsetWidth || window.innerHeight < this.element.offsetHeight; --i) {
      this.element.style.fontSize = `${i}vw`
    }
  }
}

async function application () {
  const inputs = await new Promise(resolve => {
    const inputs = []

    function touch (event) {
      // it will be replace with event.touches[event.touches.length - 1].clientX
      if (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth / 2) {
        inputs.push('RIGHT')
      } else {
        inputs.push('LEFT')
      }

      if (inputs.length === 4) {
        // it will be replace with touchstart
        window.removeEventListener('click', touch)
        resolve(inputs)
      }
    }

    // it will be replace with touchstart
    window.addEventListener('click', touch)
  })

  const text = new Text(document.getElementById('text'))
  text.write(inputs)
  text.resize()

  function resize () {
    text.resize()
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize)

  function reset () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resize)
    window.removeEventListener('dblclick', reset)
    text.erase()
    application()
  }
  window.addEventListener('dblclick', reset)
}

application()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;

  user-select: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

#text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'>
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Magic</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```